# "Unable to resolve service "Album\Controller\AlbumController" to a factory; are you certain you provided it during configuration?" in Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am getting an error in Zend Framework 2 tutorial project as,

```
Unable to resolve service "Album\Controller\AlbumController" to a factory; are you certain you provided it during configuration?
```

My Module.php as

```
namespace Album;

use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\ConfigProviderInterface;

class Module implements ConfigProviderInterface
{
public function getConfig()
{
    return include __DIR__ . '/../config/module.config.php';
}

public function getServiceConfig()
{
    return [
        'factories' => [
            Model\AlbumTable::class => function($container) {
                $tableGateway = $container->get(Model\AlbumTableGateway::class);
                return new Model\AlbumTable($tableGateway);
            },
            Model\AlbumTableGateway::class => function ($container) {
                $dbAdapter = $container->get(AdapterInterface::class);
                $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
                $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Model\Album());
                return new TableGateway('album', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
            },
        ],
    ];
}

public function getControllerConfig()
{
    return [
        'factories' => [
            Controller\AlbumController::class => function($container) {
                return new Controller\AlbumController(
                    $container->get(Model\AlbumTable::class)
                );
            },
        ],
    ];
}
}
```

And my module.config.php is;

```
namespace Album;

use Zend\Router\Http\Segment;

//use Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\InvokableFactory;

return [
'controllers' => [
    'factories' => [
        Controller\AlbumController::class => InvokableFactory::class,
    ],
],

'router' => [
    'routes' => [
        'album' => [
            'type'    => Segment::class,
            'options' => [
                'route' => '/album[/:action[/:id]]',
                'constraints' => [
                    'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                ],
                'defaults' => [
                    'controller' => Controller\AlbumController::class,
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
],

'view_manager' => [
    'template_path_stack' => [
        'album' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
    ],
],
];
```

I am very new in Zend Framework. Just can not figure out what I am doing wrong. Please mention if some more code is necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have defined two factories for "Controller\AlbumController::class"...

One in module.config.php -

```
return [
    'controllers' => [
        'factories' => [
             Controller\AlbumController::class => InvokableFactory::class,
        ],
     ],
],
```

and the second one in Module.php-

```
public function getControllerConfig()
{
    return [
        'factories' => [
            Controller\AlbumController::class => function($container) {
                return new Controller\AlbumController(
                    $container->get(Model\AlbumTable::class)
                );
            },
        ],
    ];
}
```

They are both conflicting with each other. Invokable factories are for classes that doesn't have have any dependencies. In this case it looks like "AlbumController" has a dependency of "AlbumTable", so the second option looks like the one you want.

So in short, remove the 'controllers' key value from the array in module.config.php.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes I got it, and solved that issue but the new one is **Unable to resolve service "Album\AdapterInterface" to a factory; are you certain you provided it during configuration?** , now can you please help me a bit more?

Comment: Does zend\db exist in config/modules.config.php or in the "modules" key in config/application.config.php?

Comment: Also you need to have "use Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterInterface;" in Module.php -> This seems to be your problem!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and a few other related problems - until I finally realized the real source of the issues: I was following the tutorial for Zend 2, while what I had installed is Zend 3!

If you have Zend 3, by all means use the tutorial for Zend 3, here:
https://docs.zendframework.com/tutorials/getting-started/overview/