# Unable to resolve service "Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager" to a factory; are you certain you provided it during configuration?

Tags: php

I'm trying to pass an entityManager through a factory and I'm getting an error. What can be wrong?

I use a factory putter, this is the first time I have encountered such a problem

My config:

```
'controllers' => [
    'factories' => [
        IndexController::class => IndexControllerFactory::class
    ],
],
```

My controller:

```
/**
 * @var EntityManager
 */
private $entityManager;

/**
 * Construct
 * @param EntityManager $entityManager
 */
public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager)
{
    $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
}

/**
 * Null
 * @return ViewModel
 */
public function indexAction()
{
    return parent::indexAction(); // TODO: Change the autogenerated stub
}
```

My factories:

```
<?php

namespace Admin\Factory;

use Admin\Controller\IndexController;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Interop\Container\ContainerInterface;
use Laminas\ServiceManager\Factory\FactoryInterface;
use Psr\Container\ContainerExceptionInterface;
use Psr\Container\NotFoundExceptionInterface;

class IndexControllerFactory implements FactoryInterface
{

    /**
     * @throws ContainerExceptionInterface
     * @throws NotFoundExceptionInterface
     */
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, ?array $options = null): IndexController
    {
        $entityManager = $container->get(EntityManager::class);
        return new IndexController($entityManager);
    }
}
```

php

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Unable to resolve service "Album\Controller\AlbumController" to a factory; are you certain you provided it during configuration?" in Zend Framework 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43315593/unable-to-resolve-service-album-controller-albumcontroller-to-a-factory-are)

Comment: No, this question does not solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added `DoctrineModule` and `DoctrineORMModule` to your `modules.config.php` in the overall config directory?

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).